# Getting SubLabels in App Script Function from Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

Here the problem:
I have three different categories and I wanted to group them in a unique label with three sublables. Then, i want to pick those sublabels and run my script.

Here the actual situation in Gmail:
[as is situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QPuI.png)

I want to put all those labels under a main lable nesting them like this:
[nested labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn3U1.png)

Now, nesting lables in Gmail il very easy but the main problem is when you run a script based on nested labels. Here my function:

```
function getGmailEmails(){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("UtentiSW");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  
  for(var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var j = 0; j <messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      if (message.isUnread()){
        extractDetails(message);
        GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
        }
    }
    //threads[i].removeLabel(label); //delete the label after getting the message
    
  }
  
}
```

If i try to create a nested label and pick it in the function using the name of the label as shown, does't work. It works only if i put the label in the root folder of gmail as per first picture.

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels#Label  Seems it does not allow you to group label through code.

Comment: Hi, i don't need to group labels. I have already grouped labels but i want to read a sublabels. Actually with this code doesn't work

Comment: Yeah I would agree that you have not as yet clearly described what it is you wish to accomplish.  Perhaps some more complete examples might be helpful.  I'm glad to help but I don't understand what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating Labels and Sub Labels

Create Label before Sub Labels

```
function createLabelsAndSubLabel() {
  const labels = ["Q1","Q1/1","Q1/2","Q1/3"]
  labels.forEach(l => GmailApp.createLabel(l))
}
```

- I've never tried it for more that 4 levels but if you want to extend it you can, just remember to create the labels before the sublabel or they all become separate labels and you have to go delete them and start all over again.

What it looks like in Gmail:

[image]

- Sorry my back is an image

#### Listing all of your labels in a Spreadsheet

```
function listAllLabels() {
  let labels = JSON.parse(Gmail.Users.Labels.list("me")).labels;
  let hdr = ["Name","Vis","Type","id"]
  let o = labels.map(obj => [obj.name,obj.messageListVisibility,obj.type,obj.id]);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.clearContents();
  o.unshift(hdr);
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o).sort({column:1,ascending:true});
}
```

- Gmail API needs to be enabled

In regard to your last comment I added this code to create sub labels to an existing label

```
function createLabelsAndSubLabel() {
  const labels = ["Q1/3/1","Q1/3/2","Q1/3/3"]
  labels.forEach(l => GmailApp.createLabel(l))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I didn't expressed well my problem. What I need is to read a sublabel email. 

Actually I tried to do it but with the function above doesn't work. It works only if the label is on the root of Gmail.

Comment: In regard to your last comment please see my example I created sublabel for labels that were not on the root.  I added sublabels to Q1/3